# Store a session only after a specific condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session

if i do db.sessions.find({}) we found a record, even if you do execute the next() method.

I need that the record in database (sessions store) be created only when necessary and not ever a new request appear. I want store  any information in mongodb after a specific condition be true.
I need that the record in database be created only when necessary.

I created a session store and i would use it like a middleware:

```
var sessionStore = express.session({
    store: new MongoStore({
      url: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/3xam9l3'
    }),
    secret: '1234567890QWERTY'
});
```

Specific when i want use session, i do something like that:

```
app.get('/home', sessionStore, function(req, res) {
 ...
}
```

how do this ?

[]'s

Comment: First, this seems like premature optimization. What's the reasoning for it? Second, seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15877342/nodejs-express-apply-session-middleware-to-some-routes

Comment: @FelipeLeusin Not exist reason to create I/O cicles. Is unnecessary. I reached a temporary solution. Anyway the session will be created in memory but it only be stored if a specific property of the session did created. See in https://github.com/alvieirajr/connect-mongo/blob/master/lib/connect-mongo.js#L246 (Line 247-249)

Comment: @FelipeLeusin became clear now?

Comment: Not really, but if it works for you, the best. Did you checked the question I posted?

Comment: I saw the another post, but it only show how we must use the session store like middleware (initialize the session middleware and directly specify wich routes you want sessions). I already do that. My problem is the condicional store  session, not when a must create or use a session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reached a temporary solution. Anyway the session will be created in memory but it only be stored if a specific property of the session did created.

See in https://github.com/alvieirajr/connect-mongo/blob/master/lib/connect-mongo.js#L247

Answer (score 0):

Im not pretty sure if I understand your question but here comes my answer.
In app we can use this:

```
app.use(session({secret: config.session.secret, saveUninitialized: true, resave: true}));
```

In the middleware you can use a condition like this:

```
var sessionStore = function(req, res, next){
   if (validate()){
     req.userName = "Jhon";
   }
   else{
     //do something else
   }
   next();
}
```

So if validate() is true you create a variable session, if not you do something else.

Comment: Thanks, but isn't this. If you go in mongodb you will found a record created in "sessions", even if you do execute the next() method. I need that the record in database be created only when necessary.